# How to load function when open page using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is here.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        loadMainMenu();
        lessMenu();
    });
    function loadMainMenu() {
        $.getJSON('./inc/main_menu.json', function(data) {
        var html = '';
        html += '<ul>';

        $.each(data, function(entryIndex, entry) {
            if(entry.permission.indexOf(permission) >= 0){          
                if(entry.sub && entry.sub.length > 0) {                     
                    html += '<li class="child nav_box nav_box_padding-all nav_box1';

                    // 현재 페이지 해당 카테고리 클래스 추가 임시 코드
                    if(recentPage == entry.name){
                        html += ' recent';
                    }else if(entry.name == "마이페이지"){
                        html += ' mypage';
                    }
                    html += '"><a class="nav_box_label" href=' + entry.link + ' title=' + entry.permission  + '>' + entry.name + '</a><span class="less">▼</span><span class="more">▲</span><ul>';
                    $.each(entry.sub, function(key, val) {
                        html += '<li><a href=' + val.link + ' title=' + val.permission  + '>' + val.name + '</a></li>';
                    });
                    html += '</ul></li>';                       
                } else {
                    html += '<li><a href=' + entry.link + ' title=' + entry.permission  + '>' + entry.name + '</a></li>';   
                }
            }
        });

        html += '</ul>';
        $("nav").html(html);
        });

        return false;       
    }
    function lessMenu() {
        $("li.nav_box").not(".mypage").children("ul").hide();console.log("ok!");        
    }
```

li.nav_box is the element that is generated when the page is loaded with jQuery.

I can see ok message on console.

But hide function doesn't work.

When I type manually lessMenu() on console, work well.

Please give me the advice!

Comment: can you provide your HTML

Comment: *"generated when the page is loaded"* - Please elaborate on what you mean by this.  How and when is it "generated"?  If the selector doesn't find anything when you execute this code then it doesn't exist at that time.  You'd need to find it when it does exist.

Comment: I added code making menu function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadMainMenu()` is internally performing an asynchronous operation, which means you're executing `lessMenu()` before that operation has completed.

Move the `lessMenu()` call into the callback for that asynchronous operation:

```
$.getJSON('./inc/main_menu.json', function(data) {
    // the rest of your code, then...
    lessMenu();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`loadMain` is asynchronous, meaning that it doesn't happen in the "normal flow" of the rest of your code. When you call `$.getJSON` it takes some time for your code to go and get the json, while this is happening your `lessMenu` method is called, before your `$.getJSON` callback has finished executing. Instead, you want to pass in the *success* callback in your `$.getJSON` to be `lessMenu` so that only when your code has retrieved the JSON it will then fire your `lessMenu` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadMainMenu();
});

$.getJSON('./inc/main_menu.json', function(data) {
    // your code
}, lessMenu);
```